# Github's markdown API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, markdown

I'm trying to send some text to [Github's markdown API](http://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/) and get back a raw HTML representation of it.

Currently I have this code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        processData: false,
        url: "http://api.github.com/markdown/raw",
        data: {
            "text": $('#some_textarea').val()
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log("success!");
            console.log(data);
        }, 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, error);
        }
    });
```

but I get "error" (textStatus in `error` callback). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error have you got?

Comment: The value of ```textStatus``` is "error", nothing more and nothing less. Also, the value of ```error``` is empty string.

Comment: You cannot make a JSONP POST request. JSONP is always GET, since it just appends a `<script>` tag to the document. jQuery is probably doing the JSONP request as asked, which is not understood by the API.

Comment: @FelixKling I get the exact same result if I change it to "json"

Comment: Well, the API does not return JSON, it returns simple text. If you set  `dataType: "json"`, then jQuery will try to parse the response as JSON, which will fail. And if the API does not support CORS (but I seem to remember it does), you cannot make an Ajax request to it from the browser anyway.

Comment: Testing from command line with CURL, studying responce headers it doesn't seem to support CORS.

Comment: @dfsq [The docs say](http://developer.github.com/v3/#cross-origin-resource-sharing) it only works for Origin headers that match registered applications, e.g. try calendaraboutnothing.com as the Origin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to post to HTTPS not HTTP, and if you're using the raw API then

- the posted content type needs to be text/plain
- the API returns html content, not JSON or JSONP

e.g. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rupw/9rKKh/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    processData: false,
    url: "https://api.github.com/markdown/raw",
    data: "Hello world github/linguist#1 **cool**, and #1!",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success!");
        console.log(data);
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great! Beware the API has a rate limit of 60 requests per hour. If you need more you need to register as an app and authenticate.